# Delete task by clicking delete on object

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I have a simple todo app and would like to delete tasks by clicking on the delete button when they are added to the ul

I have objects stored into an array and then create an li from this together with its own delete button. The issue I am having is that I am not sure how I would make the delete button remove the task from which it was a part of.

**Build UL function**

```
function buildList(){
var item = document.getElementById('items')
item.classList = 'well well-sm';

var newLi = document.createElement('li');
//newLi.innerHTML = '';
newLi.className = 'list-group-item';

var buttons = document.createElement('container');
buttons.classList.add('buttons');

var remove = document.createElement('button');
remove.className = ' btn btn-danger btn-sm delete pull-right ';
remove.innerHTML = 'delete';


for(var i = 0; i < taskList.name.length; i++){
  var value = taskList.name[i];
  taskList.name[i].addEventListener('click', removeTask);



  newLi.innerHTML = value;
  buttons.appendChild(remove);
  newLi.appendChild(remove);
  item.appendChild(newLi);

}   
}
```

**Delete function**

```
function removeTask(value){
   this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
}
```

If you add a task and then try to delete the task, it should be deleting.
Anyone that could help me, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DDjid/y25jdqxx/1/

Comment: Please add the fiddle link

Comment: How is the `deleteTask` function called? There is not click event attached to that function?

Comment: Sorry I had the wrong function set in my code. It should be going to removeTask() and printing the task to which the delete button was associated with

Comment: Did the fiddle link work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the click handler to the button like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < taskList.name.length; i++){
  var value = taskList.name[i];
  remove.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
}
```

and update `removeItem` function like:

```
function removeItem(){
  this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
}
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y25jdqxx/28/)

Comment: Yes this way is working, however can I splice the selection that is deleted from the the array list as well ?

Comment: Could explain abt it in details like which selection are you talking about and which array list?